# TimeZone conversion On Aura Component

Tags: apex, aura

We have a custom aura component that gets the operating hours TimeZone From a service territory (GMT) value and I convert the string that is captured on the front end but as this is selected Standard OR Daylight GMT Value is always the same so at the moment the users links the operating hour to Pacific daylight time when we use the component on the front the conversion always uses the GMT value for Daylight time instead of being dynamically.

Is there a way to pass a datetime with certain timezone i.e 2023-12-10 10:00 AM  Los Angeles, and get the GMT value to be stored in salesforce?.

Comment: It is rather difficult (though not impossible, using libraries like luxon) to do time zone conversion in the browser. I recommend you pass the input data to Apex and do the conversions there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer  @PhilW do you have any function on apex in order to convert the string format date time to a specific timezone  and store the GMT?